# Estimating sample size for treatment on a continuous data with many zeros

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power

I would love to hear peoples guidance/method on approaching this problem.

I've have a large continuous reference dataset (n_ref=~50k) with lots of zeros (~95%).  I need to estimate the number of samples (n_treatment) required to undergo a "treatment" in order to observe a positive shift in the treated groups mean value relative to the reference.  n_treatment would be << n_ref.  I'm aware of power analysis and Cohen's D, but these apply to normal distributions, so I don't think they are appropriate?

How would you estimate the effect size and/or sample size?

I'm sure this has been solved many times before but I can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If its 95% zeros, that's not continuous. 5% of the distribution is continuous at best